# Difficulty in File Upload in Angular 2 using ng2-file-upload and ng2-uploader

Tags: angular

I am re writing an application into Angular and have to upload a file. The network shows me status:200 but there is no response and my back end is not receiving any file.

The Problem is .. 1. Why Request Method is OPTION ?(CORS might have something to do with this ! but i have tested on another machine where CORS is not a problem as it is on same port)

2.How to Change the Content-Type from text/plain to multipart/form-data when using the file upload code ?

3. where do i define the headers or content-type while using the file upload code of the http://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/ or http://ng2-uploader.com/docs code

This is the Network Report from browser while using the file uploader:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:5000/clari5-cc/rest/1.0/installation/upload
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:5000
Response Headers
view source
Allow:POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type:text/plain
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:5000
Origin:http://evil.com/
Referer:http://localhost:3000/
```

But my older running application used to get this data in Network Response: I can see a notable difference.

```
Request URL:http://localhost:5000/try/rest/1.0/installation/upload
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:5000
Response Headers
view source
Content-Type:application/json
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----        WebKitFormBoundaryB06sfkK4FgTODz0F
Cookie:Webstorm-e27c5fb2=42da3160-45c3-490c-a5d9-b0ed07b63022
Host:localhost:5000
Origin:http://evil.com/
Referer:http://localhost:5000/try/mainPage.html
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryB06sfkK4FgTODz0F
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadedFiles";             filename="installer.tar"
Content-Type: application/x-tar
```

here is the code and i do not have any clue how to make changes and there is no option provided as well no example ?
Any help and suggestion will be appreciated, Thank you

```
export class AppComponent {
  public uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: "http://localhost:5000/try/rest/1.0/installation/upload"});
  public hasBaseDropZoneOver:boolean = false;
  public hasAnotherDropZoneOver:boolean = false;

  public fileOverBase(e:any):void {
    this.hasBaseDropZoneOver = e;
  }

  public fileOverAnother(e:any):void {
    this.hasAnotherDropZoneOver = e;
 }
}
```

or in

```
export class AppDemoComponent implements OnInit {
 private zone: NgZone;
 private basicOptions: Object;
 private progress: number = 0;
 private response: any = {};

 ngOnInit() {
   this.zone = new NgZone({ enableLongStackTrace: false });
   this.basicOptions = {
     url: 'http://api.ng2-uploader.com:10050/upload'
   };
 }

 handleUpload(data: any): void {
   this.zone.run(() => {
     this.response = data;
     this.progress = data.progress.percent / 100;
   });
 }
}
```